# Were does tensorflow download datasets

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

What is the defualt location of downloaded data-sets in tensorflow?
For example, where can I find on my PC the CIFAR-100 dataset after running:

```
import tensorflow as tf
cifar100 = tf.keras.datasets.cifar100
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar100.load_data()
# ... a lot of training code here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default directory is (Windows):

`C:\Users\current_user_name\.keras\datasets`